Users are not initially configured properly for audio in Ubuntu Studio 24.04
This has apparently been fixed, but how do I get things fixed on an already installed system? This is a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio with installation media 24.04LTS
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntustudio-installer/+bug/2063899

I edited my question, so more information can be found there.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Firstly I'll provide a link to the Ubuntu Studio Release Notes, which contain many warnings.
https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-24-04-lts-release-notes/
Beyond notices geared at those wanting to upgrade, there is the following relating to audio

The new installer does not configure the system’s audio configuration properly. We have a first-login fix in progress.

There currently is no workaround or fix for this issue, as its still a work in progress.
This advice is coming from Erich Eickmeyer who has already responded elsewhere (this question has been crossposted on many sites/services including Matrix), and includes

no workaround currently; its still a work in progress, meeting SRU requirements


In ubiquity and calamares, we had the capability to add the initial user to the audio group. We lost that capability with the new provisioning, and the bug is fixed but undergoing SRU 7-day gestation.

If you want details on SRU fixes & required waits; I'll refer you to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates
The current advice is to please WAIT.
Thanks for this response should go to Erich & the Ubuntu Studio team (who responded here [via me] on IRC)
